# how to find local restaurants by postcodes in asp.net mvc?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a website like http://just-eat.co.uk/ or http://hungryhouse.co.uk/ .

by this websites you can find local restaurants by your postcode.

question is how can i find restaurants by postcodes ? I should use Google map API ? it seems this websites do not use Google map API.

someone Help me !

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Answer (score 1):

try using factual. They have a really easy restful api that I find really easy to use. But the only fallback is that you only have a limited number of calls to their database unless you pay. But the starting call limit is pretty good if you're not trying to do anything large scale.

http://www.factual.com/